# Workflow Planning Template

Tags: professional

I am currently studying commercial cookery and need to prepare a workflow plan for a practical assessment, I am wondering if anyone has a good workflow template that I could use?

Comment: Dude, are you from ASTHM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ever heard of [Gantt charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart)? They can be extremely useful for [visualizing how you're going to work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9503).

In general terms, your instructors will be looking not so much at the form of your plan, but at its content. They want to see that you have thought logically and carefully about each task you have to complete, and have budgeted time carefully.

For example, if you have to cook some pasta, they will want to see that you're putting the water on to boil before working on the sauce; you should always start the 'set it and forget it' tasks early on, so you have time to work on everything else, and (hopefully) everything comes together at more or less the same time.

[image]